# Showing the limit points of E are equal to the limit points of E closure.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, field-theory

I am looking at a proof to the above statement that goes as follows:

Let p $\in E'$, then by definition, any neighborhood of p contains a element q such that q $\neq$ p and q $\in E$.

And because we know $E \subset \overline{\rm E} $ (being the closure of E), this implies that q $\in$  $\overline{\rm E}$ which implies p $\in \overline{\rm E}'$ (being the closure of the set of limit points of E).

The final statement of this part of the proof is that this implies $E' \subset \overline{\rm E}'$.

My question is how does p $\in E'$ and p $\in \overline{\rm E}'$ imply that $E'$ is a subset of $\overline{\rm E}'$? It seems just as clear that you could say the other way around as well?

Comment: You begin with any point $p\in E'$, then you showed that $p\in\overline{E}'$. This is the same as any point in $E'$ is also in $\overline{E}'$. Hence $E'\subset\overline{E}'$. To complete the proof, you need to show the reversed direction as well, that is, starting with a point in $\overline E'$, prove that it is also in $E'$.

Comment: Because $p$ is arbitrary. If for all $x\in A$ we also have $x\in B$, then $A\subset B$.

Comment: You showed that for an arbitrary $p \in E'$, that $p\in \overline{E'}$. Thus, all elements of $E'$ must also be elements of $\overline{E'}$. This means $E' \subset \overline{E'}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true by the definition of a subset.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. We say that $A$ is a subset of $B$, if for every element $a\in A$, the same element $a\in B$. This is denoted as $A\subseteq B$.

Your example considers an arbitrary element $p\in E'$, and then shows that $p\in \overline{E}'$. Thus, every element in $E'$ is in $\overline{E}'$, and $E'\subseteq \overline{E}'$.